# How To Get Same Value When Reversing a Percentage Value

Tags: c#

I'm adding a percentage to a double and want to get back the exact same number when subtracting the sames percentage.

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
double priceDouble = Convert.ToDouble(2.75);

// increase by 5%
priceDouble += priceDouble * 5 / 100; //priceDouble  = 2.8875
double x = Math.Truncate(priceDouble * 100) / 100; // x = 2.88

 // reverse - decrease by 5%
 priceDouble -= priceDouble * 5 / 100; // priceDouble = 2.743125
 x = Math.Truncate(priceDouble * 100) / 100; // x = 2.74 instead of 2.75
```

Comment: You are truncating away a part of the number. What did you expect? If you were to round, rather than truncate, your oddball calculations would work. I still think that it wouldn't work in all cases

Comment: Your "reverse" code is missing the part to untruncate the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maths doesn't work like this. You're increasing something by a percentage and then decreasing the *result* by the same percentage, which doesn't get you back to the same number. Using bigger numbers helps illustrate it:

```
100 plus  50% (of 100) is 150
150 minus 50% (of 150) is 75

75 is not 100
```

If you want to boost 200 to 210 by adding 5% then to return to where you were before you have to multiply your 210 by 100/105 (ie subtract 0.047619047619048% of the new value)

It's going to be easier to multiply and divide to change your value than add and subtract

```
double original = 2.75
double boosted = original * 1.05 //add 5%
double returned = boosted / 1.05 //sub 5%
```

Or in the case where you're modifying your original variable

```
double z = 2.75;
z*=1.05;
z\=1.05;
```

Oh, and I recommend to round rather than truncate. If you ever get a decimal value that cannot be accurately represented in `double` and your `returned` result ends up at eg 25.399999999999997 instead of 25.4 then truncating will give 25.39 rather than 25.4

Perhaps use `decimal` instead of double (do not use double for money)

Comment: Works fine with using Double. Thanks SO much Caius. Works great

Answer (score 1):

The real issue faced by OP is correctly stated and answered by [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145245/13961650) above. While this answer is just a suggestion on using `Decimal` type for real world values.

Floating point variables like `float` and `double` are not precise in most of the languages as they are in binary form. You should use decimal instead especially for real world values like currency.

Second you are truncating the values so you are compromising the accuracy.

#### References

1. [.Net Floating point numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)
2. [Tips using Floating Points](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/29637/five-tips-for-floating-point-programming) by [John D Cook](https://www.codeproject.com/Members/John-D-Cook)
3. [Floating issue in Pyhton](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)